# which is the fastest way of cloning an c# arraylist

Tags: c#, .net, c#-2.0

As the subj line makes it almost clear, i want to know what difference would cloning of a normal arraylist make if i do either of these in my overriden Clone() method.

MyArraylist is simply a derivative of a normal arraylist.

**OPTION 1**

```
return new MyArraylist(this);
```

**OPTION 2**

```
MyArraylist temp = new MyArraylist();
temp = (MyArraylist)this.Clone();
return temp;
```

where **this** refers to the Arraylist in focus which needs to be **Cloned**.
and my arraylist class has an overloaded constructor

```
public MyArrayList(MyArrayList oArrayList)
{
    lock (oArrayList.SyncRoot)
    {
        foreach (object oObject in oArrayList)
        {
            if (oObject is ICloneable)
            {
                this.Add(((ICloneable)oObject).Clone());
            }
            else
            {
                this.Add(oObject);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a performance hit that is incurred if i use as in OPTION 1. for a relatively bigger list?

Hopefully i'm clear

Comment: How about measuring via using the Stopwatch Class or by comparing the IL code in reflector?

Comment: What does this.Clone() do? What exactly are you doing? Are you inheriting from ArrayList? If so, you'd have to use base.Clone()... That being said, there most likely wouldn't be a performance hit. And on a different note, use System.Collections.Generic.List instead of ArrayList.

Comment: Sorry .. even i realised it after posting it. Now that i have edited it. Hopefully it makes it complete

Comment: sorry my company browser sucks big time. I cannot format the post. I specifically want this to be done on an arraylist and not List<>

Comment: @this-Me: Out of interest, *why* are you using `ArrayList` instead of `List<T>`?

Comment: Hi Jon, these are present inside the base class libraries ever since .NET 1.1 and i do not have a "say" to change it though we have migrated to 3.5 :(. Stupid it may seem we are not leveraging 99% of the new features offered by .NET 3.5. I have been learning a lot from your book "C# in depth" :) thanks

Answer (score 0):

After you have posted your code, I think you are comparing cloning solely the Array list (option 1) vs cloning the array list plus cloning any cloneable object inside the Array list against each other.
Edit: The array list is just an object on its own containing references. Thus a new just creates a new array list. So you have 2 array lists and x objects. The second option will create a new array list and will clone the refered objects as well, thus you will have to 2 array lists and 2*x objects.
 
It depends on your requirements, if you need option 1 or option 2. Option 1 will always be faster as it is less work.

Comment: Could you please explain me why do you think this.Clone() involves more work.

Comment: @weismat: The locking is for an *incoming* object reference - that object may already be in use in other threads. Only one thread knows about the *new* object, but the lock is on `oArrayList.SyncRoot`.

Comment: You are right, I missed that, but if it is my own class I would never ever give locking responsibilty to something outside of my class.

Comment: I have added something to explain it more in detail.